# Refresh parent window after closing a popup window

Tags: javascript, popup

I am opening a popup window from X.jsp and the popup is represented by Y.jsp. The second jsp has a button. What I would like to do is to refresh the parent page (the one that launches the popup) once this button is hit. The Save button below will call a method in the backing bean "copyScriptForVersion" and I close the popup on button click. How could I also refresh the parent window after closing the popup?

```
 <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Save" action="#{copyScriptForVersion.SaveAction}" onclick="window.close()"/>
```

I tried adding window.opener.reload() like this onclick="window.close(); window.opener.reload();", but that didn't work.

I also tried adding the following
        body onUnLoad="window.opener.location.reload(1);">

But, I got "window.opener.location is null or not an object" error.

Comment: try closing the window AFTER you reload the opener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should do `window.close()` as a LAST action in the onClick handler. Otherwise, it's possible it will never get executed.

Second, if reload() doesn't work, try:

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href; window.close();
```

Please note that this may cause problems if the parent page was produced as a result of POSTing a form.

Comment: I tried both, but I got "window.opener.reload is null or not an object"

Comment: Same error, I also tried opener.reload and opener.opener.reload based on a few sites. Nothing works as of now.

Comment: "is null or not an object" for href as well?

Comment: Yep. It doesn't like window.opener.reload when I use href.

Comment: What are you talking about? I specifically said not to use href if you read the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help other as well,,

```
`new = window.open(url);
        new.focus();
        check = setInterval(function() {
            if (new.closed) {
                window.location.reload(true)
            }}, 1000);`
```