# Why this window.opener.reload is not a function error?

Tags: javascript

I have a snippet like this.

```
if (window.opener != null) {
    window.opener.reload();
}
```

When called, firebug shows,

> TypeError: window.opener.reload is not a function

And Chrome console says,

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'reload'

What could be wrong?

P.S: `typeof window.opener` is `"object"`.

Comment: What does `typeof window.opener.reload` show?

Comment: anyway, have a look at this link wich might be a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571860/refresh-parent-window-after-closing-a-popup-window

Comment: @RicardoAppleton: what has this got to do with jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reload` is a method of the `location` object, not the `window` object.

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

Comment: I tried that in console and it gave me "undefined". let me run it in browser

Comment: that did it. any idea on why it returns undefined in console? just curious on how that happens. thanks anyway

Comment: It doesn't return undefined for me. (Unless you are talking about `window.opener.reload` again, which is undefined simply because nothing defines it).